# How to add data from a Google map as layer in ArcMap using C#?

Tags: arcmap, development, google-maps-api

I want to use C# to write a tool: add data from google map as a layer in ArcMap. I am  using ArcGIS 10.0.

Can you help me?

Comment: what do you mean by 'data google map'? Do you want to add the satellite images etc as a layer? That is against the Terms of Use of Google Maps.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use ArcGis and Arc2Earth. It is very expensive, but legally

Answer (score 0):

http://arcbrutile.codeplex.com allows you to load basemaps different providers, but no google for legal reasons.
It is open source and can also be used as an api for your own applications.